# Why do I get 'INSERT has more target columns than expressions' when executing this insert with unnest statement for my postgresql table?

Tags: postgresql, insert, unnest

> ERROR:  INSERT has more target columns than expressions

I get the above error when running the below query:

```
INSERT INTO studio (imageId, job, imageName, imagePath, imageWidth, created_at, lastModified, imageYear, imageServiceType, imageClient, imageCategory, imageCountry, imageThumbnail) 
SELECT * FROM UNNEST(ARRAY[
    ['01GNYB5KJTYRQ4WY5PKNE3C6RRBTZH3RFK', 'GC092', 'GC092 - Alcon Qual Cataract Screener', '/SHELFA1_HR.jpg', '5120', '2023-4-5', '2023-03-27T15:49:37Z', '2023', 'Pack LAB', 'ALCON', 'OTHER', 'Brazil, France, Germany, Japan, Spain, USA', 'thumbnail'],
    ['01GNYB5KMGENM2ETF6UREZBET4B42KS3MQ', 'GC130', 'GC130 - Alcon Shelf Navigation Conjoint', '/SHELF1_AUS.jpg', '5120', '2023-4-5', '2023-03-27T15:16:06Z', '2023', 'Other', 'ALCON', 'HEALTH & BEAUTY - OTHER', 'Brazil, USA, Australia', 'thumbnail']
]);
```

This query below, inserting a single row with VALUES works fine:

```
INSERT INTO studio (imageId, job, imageName, imagePath, imageWidth, created_at, lastModified, imageYear, imageServiceType, imageClient, imageCategory, imageCountry, imageThumbnail) VALUES ('01GNYB5KJTYRQ4WY5PKNE3C6RRBTZH3RFK','GC092 - Alcon Qual Cataract Screener','SHELFA1_HR.jpg','/SHELFA1_HR.jpg','5120','2023-4-5','2023-03-27T15:49:37Z','2023','Pack LAB','ALCON','OTHER','Brazil, France, Germany, Japan, Spain, USA','thumbnail')
```

But I want to insert multiple rows of data concisely with the UNNEST function. There are 13 columns specified and 13 expressions passed, but the error suggests otherwise. I have and 'id' primary key which does not need to be included. Please help me understand why the first query is not valid.

Comment: Well, your unnest [returns only one column](https://dbfiddle.uk/U5BniMDw). But why an array with unnest? Why not just use a [VALUES clause](https://dbfiddle.uk/J0OJ9YC3)?

Comment: You could have tried the UNNEST yourself to see how it works. But, it's clearly also the wrong data type (and structure) because you have mix of different data types, all presenting themselves as text. As said before, use VALUES() to fix these issues.